# Can I use single event for two different field change and redirect to different method in apex controller accordingly

Tags: lightning-aura-components, event

Lightning component

```
<aura:handler event="c:SVC_SearchOnKeyChange" action="{!c.searchTabChange}"/>
<ui:inputText aura:id="caseSubject" class="slds-input" value="{!v.Case.Subject}" change="{!c.searchKeyChange}" updateOn="change" required="true"/>
<ui:inputTextArea aura:id="caseDescription" class="slds-input" value="{!v.Case.Description}" required="true"/>
```

Controller.JS

```
//Value of Event
searchKeyChange: function(component, event, helper) {
   var myEvent = $A.get("e.c:SVC_SearchOnKeyChange");
   myEvent.setParams({"searchKey": event.getSource().get("v.value")});
   myEvent.fire();
},

// Results of value on tab change of subject and description field
searchTabChange: function(component, event) {
   var source = event.getSource().getElement();
   console.log(source);
   var classN = source.ClassName;
   var searchKey = event.getParam("searchKey");
   var action = component.get("c.fetchArticlesBySubject");
   action.setParams({
     "searchKey": searchKey
   });
   action.setCallback(this, function(a) {
       component.set("v.articles", a.getReturnValue());
   });
   $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

Want to define action according to subject or description with single function.`enter code here`

Comment: You can specify a name when you add your handler and event register. I never tried that but I suppose that you can handle the same event with different names specified.

Comment: We can use event.getSource().getLocalId(); which gives id of field who triggered event and accordingly we can call different method of apex controller

Answer (score 0):

```
event.getSource().getLocalId();
```

Use above which gives id of field who triggered event and accordingly we can call different method of apex controller.
In my case it returns caseSubject or caseDescription